# How to keep my text on the same line with AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to keep my ajax call on the same line, as detailed here: http://external.sidewaykill.com/versound/motd.php.

It won't, so what can I do?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup ({
  cache: false
 });
 var ajax_load = "<img src='http://static.sidewaykill.com/img/ajax-loader2.gif' alt='loading...' />";

// load() functions
 var loadUrl = "playercount.php?id=2";
  $("#servercount").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
 });
```

Comment: Don't understand "keep my ajax call on the same line". And can you give us your PHP source.

Comment: I second that question ^ No idea what you're asking.

Comment: Note that I want the text to stay within the black header bar. Look at the page I linked, and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `PHP` but everything to do with the absolutely awful markup of your HTML and the lack of `CSS`. You're going to want to wrap all of this "free-text" inside of a `div` or two, and then make sure you're putting the `wrapper` `div` inside of the `infobar` `div`

Sample CSS:

```
#infobar p{
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="infobar">
  <div style="float: left;">
        <p>Welcome! Our server count is:</p> 
        <p>1 / 10</p>
        <p>We hope you enjoy your stay! We are currently playing on gm_construct.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you are seeing the CloudFlare cached version of my site, so everything is minified. If you want to see the actual source, you can see it at http://direct.sidewaykill.com/~sidewayk/external/versound/motd.php

Answer (score 0):

its because the ajax call returning a div element,

as this :

```
<div id="count"> 0 / 10</div>
```

Since div is a block element it will always render in a new line. there are two solutions for this

one would be to return a `<span>` element instead of the div

second will be if u are unable to change the return value you can fix it via css

```
#servercount #count { display : inline }
```

My suggestion is to go with the first solutions

Comment: Haha thanks, I had to change the server count finder page, to make the DIV inline.

Comment: if u have access to the server count finder page why not make it `<span id="count"> 0 / 10</span>` ?